Disable namespaces in Linux without compiling
Is there a way to disable all namespace types at boot time or runtime in Linux?

"Without compiling" ? Do you mean without rebuilding the kernel after having ensured CONFIG_USER_NS = [n] ?

I'am also curious to know why you would want that since many applications resort on namespaces for sandboxing. Embedded system ?

Even basic system services started via systemd rely on namespace support for features like PrivateTmp and other sorts of protection.

@MC68020 Namespaces went too far and many tools crap on them. Not surprisingly, no *BSD has them, even the freebsd jail is now obsolete. If it is really useful or not, another question, I believe some paravirtualization is still useful. FreeBSD has a paravirtualization accelerator called bhyve, similar to kvm, of course not kvm because they would not ever do anything what linux does. But no namespaces.

@MC68020 No. My problem is that namespaces complicate AppArmor policy. A separate mount namespace could have sn entirely different root mount that wouldn't need to be protected by AppArmor policy or it could mount the root filesystem at a path that policy would let a process write to, for example.

@MC68020 And yes, without recompiling.

For each type of namespace, the maximum number of namespaces per user (root included) can be defined via sysctl.
As listed under my linux 5.4 (*) :
Tux /proc/sys/user # sysctl -a | grep namespace
user.max_cgroup_namespaces = 31889
user.max_ipc_namespaces = 31889
user.max_mnt_namespaces = 31889
user.max_net_namespaces = 31889
user.max_pid_namespaces = 31889
user.max_user_namespaces = 31889
user.max_uts_namespaces = 31889

Disabling user ID namespaces at run time can then be as simple as running :
sudo sysctl -w user.max_user_namespaces=0

Enabling this setting to be taken into account at init time will depend on your init system. (editing /etc/sysctl.conf and having the sysctl service configured set to start at boot on openrc for example)
Proceeding that way with each sysctl will actually disable all types of namespaces.
However, I strongly discourage you to proceed (disabling all of them) without having a perfect knowledge of your system & applications running since just many common applications (as well as even some system features and services) are likely to need namespaces support for operating.
The very least would be to run lsns -l with your system running its typical workload in order to list information about all the currently accessible namespaces, as, for now on my system :
acoswt@Tux ~ $ sudo lsns -l
        NS TYPE   NPROCS   PID USER   COMMAND
4026531835 cgroup    126     1 root   init [3]  
4026531836 pid       108     1 root   init [3]  
4026531837 user      108     1 root   init [3]  
4026531838 uts       126     1 root   init [3]  
4026531839 ipc       126     1 root   init [3]  
4026531840 mnt       125     1 root   init [3]  
4026531860 mnt         1    18 root   kdevtmpfs
4026531992 net       108     1 root   init [3]  
4026532251 pid         2  2061 acoswt /usr/lib64/chromium-browser/chrome --type=zygote…
4026532253 net        18  2061 acoswt /usr/lib64/chromium-browser/chrome --type=zygote…
4026532276 user       18  2061 acoswt /usr/lib64/chromium-browser/chrome --type=zygote…

The first ten lines telling me that I would not be wise disabling any one of the namespace types ;-)

(*) Higher versions of the linux kernel might show more tuneables when support is added for more namespace types. e.g.  max_time_namespaces since support for time namespaces landed in linux-5.6

Indeed, even Firefox uses namespaces (if available) for isolation.
